# Why does this css animated Infinite autoplay carousel jump when the items reset?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm working to create an infinite autoplay carousel based on the example here: https://codepen.io/jackoliver/pen/qVbQqW

Notice how smooth the codepen example is, it never jumps when the carousel resets from the last to first item.

Mine is less smooth - Mine is jumping on reset and I can't figure out why...

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-456px * 2));
  }
}
.quotes-famous {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.quotes-famous::before, .quotes-famous::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.quotes-famous::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.quotes-famous::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.quotes-famous__track {
  animation: scroll 1s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(456px * 4);
}

.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-famous">
   <div class="quotes-famous__track">
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Quisque at lorem sollicitudin, elementum justo a, dictum tortor. Donec dapibus elementum augue, in imperdiet lorem posuere nec. Sed scelerisque scelerisque imperdiet. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The codepen example doubles up on all the images (or quotes in your case).

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-456px * 2));
  }
}
.quotes-famous {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.quotes-famous::before, .quotes-famous::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.quotes-famous::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.quotes-famous::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.quotes-famous__track {
  animation: scroll 4s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(456px * 4);
}

.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-famous">
   <div class="quotes-famous__track">
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Quisque at lorem sollicitudin, elementum justo a, dictum tortor. Donec dapibus elementum augue, in imperdiet lorem posuere nec. Sed scelerisque scelerisque imperdiet. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Quisque at lorem sollicitudin, elementum justo a, dictum tortor. Donec dapibus elementum augue, in imperdiet lorem posuere nec. Sed scelerisque scelerisque imperdiet. </p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```