# Why does a min-width property break this css animated Infinite autoplay carousel?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Why does adding min-width break the smoothness of the animation?

If the code snippet uses the following it works perfectly (not jumping)

```
.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;
  margin: 0 32px;
}
```

Problem is I need a min-width of 456px which causes it to break. Why?

```
.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;
  min-width: 456px;
  margin: 0 32px;
}
```

Why does the min-width cause this animation to break, be jumpy and not appear like an infinite carousel?

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-456px * 2));
  }
}
.quotes-famous {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.quotes-famous::before, .quotes-famous::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.quotes-famous::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.quotes-famous::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.quotes-famous__track {
  animation: scroll 2s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(456px * 4);
}

.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;
  min-width: 456px;
  margin: 0 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-famous">
   <div class="quotes-famous__track">
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAA.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAA.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, can you see it work perfectly without the min-width property... I need the div width to be 456px which is why I have the min-width set as a css property. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48813226/why-does-this-css-animated-infinite-autoplay-carousel-jump-when-the-items-reset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a matter of calculation. You need to adjust the `calc` of the transform like below considering the width of 4 elements and their margin:

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc((-456px * 4) - (8 * 32px)));
  }
}
.quotes-famous {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.quotes-famous::before, .quotes-famous::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.quotes-famous::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.quotes-famous::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.quotes-famous__track {
  animation: scroll 4s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(456px * 4);
}

.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;
  min-width: 456px;
  margin: 0 32px;
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-famous">
   <div class="quotes-famous__track">
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAA.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAA.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <p class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

See it here https://jsfiddle.net/j5nuc7s1/5/

I made 2 changes:
1) Added new class
2) Changed p to div

```css
body {
  align-items: center;
  background: #E3E3E3;
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  justify-content: center;
}

@keyframes scroll {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(calc(-456px * 2));
  }
}
.quotes-famous {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 20px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
  height: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
.quotes-famous::before, .quotes-famous::after {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, white 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
  content: "";
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.quotes-famous::after {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: rotateZ(180deg);
}
.quotes-famous::before {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.quotes-famous__track {
  animation: scroll 2s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  width: calc(456px * 4);
}

.quotes-famous__quote {
  background: #efefef;
  height: 500px;
  width: 456px;      
  margin: 0 32px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
/* added new */
.quotes-famous__quote .quotes-famous__text{
  min-width: 456px;      
}
```

```html
<div class="quotes-famous">
   <div class="quotes-famous__track">
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAA.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">AAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAA AA A A A A A A AAAAAAAA AAAA.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">Phasellus dictum leo enim, a dignissim erat vestibulum at. Sed vitae libero id mauris ullamcorper elementum. Praesent at accumsan ipsum. Quisque sit amet posuere mauris. Proin ac vulputate odio, quis faucibus sem. Cras nec consectetur neque.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">Sed sagittis ligula ut est faucibus egestas.</div>
      </div>
      <div class="quotes-famous__quote">
         <div class="quotes-famous__text">Fusce convallis, risus et luctus tempus, urna orci accumsan tortor, accumsan euismod arcu lectus vitae neque. Nulla tincidunt, augue non efficitur euismod, nunc diam feugiat turpis, convallis lacinia velit enim et nisl. Sed at suscipit augue. Curabitur sed dolor metus. Nunc augue eros, aliquet sed mi ac, pulvinar fermentum mauris. Cras condimentum sapien tellus, nec efficitur odio imperdiet vitae.</div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but that doesn't address the issue of needing the quotes-famous__quote DIV to be a width of 456px, your jsfiddle, the div is only ~160pixels wide... That's why I need to add the min-width of 456px - but that's what breaks the smooth animation

Comment: Jump happens only on the first element?